# How to count the number of days, weeks, months in a date column of a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, date, datetime

With `format()` I can extract year, month and day as follows:

```
date        day       month     year
<date>      <fctr>    <fctr>    <fctr>
    
2005-01-01  01        01        2005    
2005-01-01  01        01        2005    
2005-01-02  02        01        2005    
2005-01-02  02        01        2005    
2005-01-03  03        01        2005    
2005-01-03  03        01        2005    
...

2010-12-31  31        12        2010    
2010-12-31  31        12        2010    
2010-12-31  31        12        2010    
2010-12-31  31        12        2010    
2010-12-31  31        12        2010
2010-12-31  31        12        2010
```

However, I also want to count how many days,weeks,months there are, from the start to the end. That is, I want to create day,week,month numbers as follows:

```
date        day       month     year     day_num    week_num    month_num
<date>      <fctr>    <fctr>    <fctr>   <double>   <double>    <double>
    
2005-01-01  01        01        2005     1          1           1
2005-01-01  01        01        2005     1          1           1
2005-01-02  02        01        2005     2          1           1
2005-01-02  02        01        2005     2          1           1
2005-01-03  03        01        2005     3          1           1
2005-01-03  03        01        2005     3          1           1
...

2005-02-28  28        02        2005     59         9           2
2005-03-01  01        03        2005     60         9           3
2005-03-02  02        03        2005     61         9           3
...
```

How can I do that without miscounting?

Comment: Isn't the month_num, just `as.numeric(as.character(month))` and perhaps `format(date, '%W')` for week_num, and `match(date, unique(date))` for `day_num

Comment: No. in month column "01" represents "January", similarly "02" represents "February" and so on. But by month_num I want to see how many months there are in my data from the start to the end and add this information as a separate column

Comment: ok, may be your example was not clear as the 'month' and 'month_num' shows the same output except the type

Comment: day_num and week_num are more clear then. idea behind the calculation of all these 3 variables is the same actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `format()` with the following codes:

```
date = strptime('2005-02-28', format='%Y-%m-%d')

format(date, '%j') # Decimal day of the year

format(date, '%U') # Decimal week of the year (starting on Sunday)

format(date, '%W') # Decimal week of the year (starting on Monday)

format(date, '%m') # Decimal month
```

Output:

```
[1] "059"
[1] "09"
[1] "09"
[1] "02"
```

[Source](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/dates.html)

Comment: This is way easier!

Comment: Yes, it computes it separately for every year, but it shouldn't start from the beginning when it's done with a year and goes on to next. What I mean is that as follows. ```for 2005-01-01;  day: 1, week: 0, month: 1. for 2005-12-31; day: 365, week: 52, month: 12```, but ```for 2006-01-01;  day: 1, week: 0, month: 1``` again, but I want it to continue, that is ```for 2006-01-01;  day: 366, week: 53, month: 13``` and similarly ```for 2006-12-31;  day: 730, week: 104, month:24```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `difftime` to get the number of days and weeks but you need a workaround for the number of months. This will do the trick:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    day_num = as.numeric(difftime(date, min(date), units = "days")),
    week_num = floor(as.numeric(difftime(date, min(date), units = "weeks"))),
    tmp = year(date) * 12 + month(date),
    month_num = tmp - min(tmp)
  ) %>% 
  select(-tmp)
```

Comment: Yes, it computes it separately for every year, but it shouldn't start from the beginning when it's done with a year and goes on to next. What I mean is that as follows. for 2005-01-01;  day: 1, week: 0, month: 1. for 2005-12-31; day: 365, week: 52, month: 12, but for 2006-01-01;  day: 1, week: 0, month: 1 again, but I want it to continue, that is for 2006-01-01;  day: 366, week: 53, month: 13 and similarly for 2006-12-31;  day: 730, week: 104, month:24